# Client Credentials Grant Flow having subject with null value, cause internal server error

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I have a windows service (no user interaction) which makes calls protected services (say for example makes calls to REST / WEB API). I tried to use Client Credentials Flow, but looks like IdentityServer3 does not understand Client Credentials flow. The subject value (supposed to contain ClaimsPrincipal object) is null. Any idea what is the issue here? Does IdentityServer3 supports Client Credentials flow? What is the correct way of using Client Credentials flow with IdentityServer3?

The following is my client code, which eventually gets the response as Internal Server error from IdentityServer3:

```
 var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        var client = new TokenClient(
            Constants.TokenEndpoint,
            "client",
            "secret", handler);

        return client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("read write").Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

IdentityServer 3 does support the Client Credentials OAuth Grant Type (see [Flow property on the Client class](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/clients.html)).

The fault will be a configuration issue, so switch on [logging for IdentityServer](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/logging.html), it will be telling you why the request is failing.

#### Correct Flow for Access Token with Subject Claim

To get an access token that can access a protected resource on behalf of a user then a grant type/flow must be used that has knowledge of a user/identity.

Client Credentials is only used for machine-to-machine communication, it has no concept of a user/identity.

Ideally if the user is authenticated (they logged in to the system), you can issue them an access token at time of login. This can be done using any OpenID Connect flow (Implicit, Authorization Code or Hybrid).

If users are not authenticated, you can use the Resource Owner flow. This flow is generally considered legacy and requires the users username and password.

Comment: logging is turned on. The first error is null reference exception

Comment: So this is what you need to put in your question. Where is the exception being thrown?

Comment: at the code: var subjectid = subject.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "sub").First().Value; Function name is: GetAccessTokenClaimsAsync. The reason for this issue is, as I mentioned in my question: ClaimsPrincipal is coming as null

Comment: GetAccessTokenClaimsAsync method has ClaimsPrincipal is coming as null. So, subject.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "sub").First().Value code is failing with null reference exception

Comment: There are no humans/identity involved with ClientCredentials, therefore no subject claim. ClientCredentials is machine to machine communication only. It may help to know if you have customized IdentityServer in any way or to show your Client configuration.

Comment: no, I did not customize Identity server. So, Client Credentials Grant Flow is not the correct flow to be used for Windows service to talk to REST service? could you suggest what flow is the correct one for windows service to talk to REST service securely and authentication and authorization should work as expected.

Comment: If there is no authentication involved but you need the concept of a user then the ResourceOwner grant type is what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126091/discussion-between-venkat-naidu-and-scott-brady).

Comment: sorry, was not able to use chat. just one more comment: my REST service is configured with UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication. So I require authentication, meaning I would need authentication and authorization. It is NOT like any windows service running under any account would access REST service

Comment: See updated answer for a brief explanation of access tokens that can access protected resources on behalf of a user.

Comment: in order to user Authorization Code flow, I require code. How do I get code in windows service? should I make any explicit calls to IdentityServer to just get code? I should use any other flow to get code, before using Authorization code flow?